# Duplicate symbol error using AFNetworking framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I am using **Paynimo** Payment Gateway in my iOS app.

This framework contains **AFNetworking**, **SBjson** files in it.

My Project also contains these files for other usage. So it gives duplicate symbols errors for those file. When I try to remove any one of those files, it gives error of file not found.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to remove any one. Next job is select files from project & include in `target membership` see attached

.[image: see attached]

Answer (score 0):

Consider dependency manager like CocoaPods(https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) or Carthage (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage)

Answer (score 0):

Remove afnetworking files in your app and use Paynimolib afnetworking and do the following.

1.#import 
2.AFHttpoperationmanager replace to AFHttpsessionmanager